# Is it possible to create a LASCatalog with lidR that reference LAS files in multiple directories?

Tags: r, lidr

As new or updated LAS data is received, I would like to be able to integrate that into the surrounding data of the area (for normalized data, CHMs, etc. for example). I.e. I want to insert "patches" that take advantage of lidR's buffering capability, but to have LAS files organized in different spots (e.g. based on date acquired). I don't think lidR is meant as a data management tool but binding catalogs together with `catalog_intersect` might be helpful in this case. edit: or `ctg$processed` instead of `catalog_intersect`

edit July 05, 2022: update following the answer from below. This is an alternative to using list.files() that may be helpful. It reads in a csv file that has been put together and edited outside of R so specific las/laz files could be targeted.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(readr)
library(lidR)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Alternative to list.files('D:/Test/LASLAZ', pattern = '*.la*')
#
# First prepare a list of las or laz files through the dos prompt:
# dir *.la* /B /A-D /S > laslazList.csv
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

setwd("D:/Test/")

LASfiles_Raw <- read_csv('laslazList.csv', col_names = 'filename')
LASfiles_Raw <- as.list(LASfiles_Raw$filename)
LASfiles_Raw <- as.character(LASfiles_Raw[])

ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfiles_Raw,
                      progress = TRUE,
                      select = "xyzcr",
                      filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -5")
plot(ctg)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally have a `LAScatalog` where the LAS files are stored in different folders. The simplest is to have a root folder

```
project/
|__ subfolder1/
|__ subfolder2/
    |__ subsubfolder1/
    |__ subsubfolder2/
```

In this case you can simply use

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog("project/", recursive = TRUE)
```

For more complex folder architectures (e.g. you don't want all the files to be included ; you don't have a root project or whatever) you can programatically list all the LAS files you want with R functions like `list.files()` and give a vector of files to `readLAScatalog()`

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog(vector_of_file_paths)
```

However you cannot bind two `LAScatalog` it becomes a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` by inheritance and because `lidR` does not define `bind` functions. This might be a good feature request btw

```r
rbind(ctg1, ctg2)
#> class : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
```

**edit: `rbind` added in lidR 3.2.0**

```r
rbind(ctg1, ctg2)
#> class : LAScatalog
```

Comment: Perfect. So now I can read files in the new folder, remove the old files based on name or location, and create a new catalog to work with. How do I make a feature request? A `catalog_replace` would save a few steps for me!

Comment: Feature request on [github](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) or if you don't have a github account send an email.